# Picking highest value between two options in field calculation using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, calculate-values

Is there a way to choose the highest value between two options when using them in a calculation?

The highest value alternates between x and y

This project is in ArcMap.

[image]

Comment: In the expression field (not code block), put `max(!XStdDist!, !YStdDist!)` when using the Python parser.

Comment: Thank you very much! Helped me solve the challenge